# Why Backbone.View object still remains in memory?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, javascript-framework

I have simple view that shows dialog box.

```
Backbone.View.prototype.completeRemove = function(){
    this.undelegateEvents();
    this.remove();
    delete this.$el;
    delete this.el;
    console.log('completely removed')
}

MdApp.dialogBox = Backbone.View.extend({

    defaults: {
        text: __('No text provided'),
        buttonText: __('Ok'),
        callback: function(){
            return null;
        },
        el: $('#app-panel'),
        type: 'error',
        cancellable: false,
        cancelText: __('No'),
        picture: pic('default')
    },

    el: '<div class="dialog-box">',

    template: _.template($('#dialog-box-template').html()),

    events: {
        'click .confirm' : 'confirm',
        'click .cancel' : 'cancel'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        this.model = _.extend(this.defaults, this.model);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function(){
        var model = this.model;
        this.$el.html(this.template(model));
        model.el.append(this.el);
    },

    confirm: function(){
        var model = this.model;
        var view = this;
        this.completeRemove();
        model.callback();
    },

    cancel: function(){
        this.completeRemove();
    }
});
```

It has its own default values. Everytime I'm initializing new dialog its values persists between every dialog invocation. For example when I'm invoking dialog for the first time:

```
new MdApp.dialogBox({model:{
        text: __('Do you really wanna delete this?'),
        buttonText: __('Unfortunately yes'),
        callback: function(){
            //some callback
        },
        cancellable: true,
        cancelText: __('No'),
        picture: pic('confirm delete')
    }});
```

After that I'm invoking another dialog without `cancellable` property so it should use default one (which is `false`), but it stays true. This applies to every other property. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

> **extend** `_.extend(destination, *sources)`
>
> Copy all of the properties in the **source** objects over to the **destination** object, and return the **destination** object.

That means that `_.extend(o, ...)` modifies `o`. So when you do this:

```
this.model = _.extend(this.defaults, this.model);
```

You are effectively doing this:

```
for(k in this.model)
    this.defaults[k] = this.model[k];
this.model = this.defaults;
```

The `defaults` is attached to the prototype so you are, in fact, changing the `defaults` that will be shared by every instance of `MdApp.dialogBox`. That's why you're ending up with sticky properties: you're merging all the various `this.model`s into the `defaults` on the view's prototype.

You could do it like this:

```
// Merge into an empty object to avoid altering this.defaults
this.model = _.extend({}, this.defaults, this.model);
```

Or you could use [`_.defaults`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) instead of `_.extend`:

> **defaults** `_.defaults(object, *defaults)`
>
> Fill in null and undefined properties in **object** with values from the **defaults** objects, and return the **object**. As soon as the property is filled, further defaults will have no effect.

So you could do this:

```
_(this.model).defaults(this.defaults);
```

This will alter `this.model` in-place so your view would be assuming that it wholly owns `this.model` and that there aren't any outside references to that object.